# problem with prototype.js Ajax functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

my code(prototype 1.6.1)

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            new Ajax.Request('/modal/order_same/', {
                parameters: {},
                onComplete: function(){alert('err0');},
                onSuccess:function(){alert('err1');},
                onCreate:function(){alert('err2');},
                onFailure:function(){alert('err3');},
                onException:function(){alert('err4');},
                onLoaded:function(){alert('err5');}
            });     
});
```

or

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            new Ajax.Updater(somelement,'/modal/order_same/', {
                parameters: {},
                onComplete: function(){alert('err0');},
                onSuccess:function(){alert('err1');},
                onCreate:function(){alert('err2');},
                onFailure:function(){alert('err3');},
                onException:function(){alert('err4');},
                onLoaded:function(){alert('err5');}
            });
});
```

all i get in ff3.7prea5 is "err2". my client says he has ff3.6.3 and same error

firebug console says he's get the response and the status code is 200

works fine in opera, ie 6-8, ff on some computers

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of alpha version of Firebug

Answer (score 0):

In my Firefox 3.6.3 bith works just fine. Can you provide us a page where it fails so we can debug it. As there is no error in your code we can't help you otherwise.

Comment: i'we found out that this code is working when the firebug(1.6 alpha) is disabled, but i beleve my client has no firebug

Comment: Is there any console.log or and other firebug function in your JS code? Can you offer a HTML file with this error?

Comment: there is no console.log() calls..it runs without firebug. i'll try to find out whats happening on my client's computer via teamviewer tomorrow.